# Stopping an infinite while loop using scanf in c?

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, scanf

I created a program that accepts 3 numbers separated by comments which I will use to do some calculations. It will accept user input for these numbers and I'm using scanf to accept that.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a, b, c;

    bool continue_program = true;

    while (continue_program) {
        printf("Enter your coordinates: ");
        scanf("%f,%f,%f", &a,&b,&c);
        if(isdigit(a) && isdigit(b) && isdigit(c)){
            printf("Success!");
        } else {
            printf("Try again!");
        }
    }
}
```

Example Output:

```
Try again!Enter your coordinates: Try again!Enter your coordinates: Try again!Enter your coordinates: Try again!Enter your coordinates: Try again!Enter your coordinates: Try again!Enter your coordinates: Try again!Enter your coordinates: Try again!Enter your coordinates: Try again!Enter your coordinates: Try again!
```

I know that other people have also faced the same issue and went through the answer for those ones but couldn't get their implementations working for this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it all wrong `scanf()` will return the number of arguments matched and you are not checking for that.

Also, the `isdigit()` function takes an integer, and returns non `0` if the ascii value of the passed argument corresponds to a digit.

To make your program stop when a condition is met, you should change the value of `continue_program` inside the loop, suppose you want to stop when `scanf()` didn't get `3` floating point numbers to read, it will return a value that is different from `3` so you can set that as the `if` condition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a, b, c;

    bool continue_program = true;

    while (continue_program) {
        printf("Enter your coordinates: ");
        if (scanf("%f,%f,%f", &a, &b, &c) == 3){
            printf("Success!");
        } else {
            continue_program = false;
            printf("Try again!");
        }
    }
}
```

This solution is suggested following the comments by the OP

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a, b, c;
    char line[100];

    printf("Enter your coordinates: ");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL) {
        size_t length;

        length = strlen(line);
        if (line[length - 1] == '\n')
            line[length - 1] = 0;
        if (strcmp(line, "0,0,0") == 0)
            break;
        if (sscanf(line, "%f,%f,%f", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
            printf("\tSuccess!\n");
        else
            printf("\tTry again!\n");
        printf("Enter your coordinates: ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay knowing how it returns values helps a lot. How do I continue to keep asking them for coordinates? Setting the boolean to false will end the entire loop.

Comment: It depends, when do you want to end the loop?

Comment: @RandomMaker: Please explain when you want the program to stop. Is it after a "success" or after a "Failure"?

Comment: I don't understand all the down votes here... Anyway I'll do a +1 for this answer.

Comment: After a specific input is submitted. Specifically 0,0,0

Comment: I would suggest a different approach, because comparing `float`s with `0` is not as simple as you think.

Comment: What approach would you suggest?

Comment: @RandomMaker use `fgtets()` to read lines and then parse that with `sscanf()`.

Comment: @RandomMaker: As iharob suggests floats are bad. Maybe you could use     char instead. Then you could also use the isdigit() as in your first attempt.

Comment: @RandomMaker i will post a simple solution that I just wrote, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

you are not updating the value of `continue_program` in your code. Hence its value remains true and hence the infinite loop.You have to update it to be false to stop it.